# How to deal with macros in ANTLR4 if they are not expanded before parsing

Tags: macros, pretty-print, antlr4

I'd like to parse code that relies on macros which should not be replaced before parsing.

After parsing I'd like to:

1. pretty print the code
2. extract some information

Therefore I thought I'll need a way to "keep" the macro somehow while still expand it to satisfy the grammar.

Some sample code similar to what I need:

In SomeFile there are some macros defined:

```
// other code...

// macro definitions look like this:
// a bunch of #define statements inside {}
// So every "{" start a macro scope (except inside strings of course)
{
  #define ASSERT if ((
  #define IS_TRUE )==true) throw new AssertionFailed();
  #define IS_FALSE )==false) throw new AssertionFailed();
  #define MULTI_LINE_MACRO they   \
                           always end in  \
                           backslashes except the last line

}

// other code...
```

In a file I want to parse:

```
// similar to "#include" in C 
import SomeFile, SomeOtherFile ;

function Myfunction : void

  ASSERT 1 == 1 IS_TRUE

end_function
```

I'd like to transform it for example into something like this:

```
import SomeFile, SomeOtherFile ;

function Myfunction : void

  ASSERT
      1 == 1
  IS_TRUE

end_function
```

And I'd also like to check if the macros are used correctly (for some "known" macros):

```
import SomeFile, SomeOtherFile ;

function Myfunction : void

  // this should not be considered ok although it will compile fine
  // It should be checked that ASSERT is followed by an expression followed by IS_TRUE
  ASSERT 1 == 1 ));
  //            ^
  // error should be here

end_function
```

Ideally it should be configurable in the macro definition source file which restrictions apply, so it would be an advantage if the checks could be made dynamically.

```
{
  #define ASSERT if ((
  #define IS_TRUE )==true) throw new AssertionFailed();
  #define IS_FALSE )==false) throw new AssertionFailed();

  // ideally I could define some semantic constraints here:
  //@@rule:: assertion : ASSERT expression (IS_TRUE|IS_FALSE) => statements
  //this should place the "assertion" rule in the statements section of the grammar
}

// other code...
```